# grayscale image on webcam using opencv (cant show full image)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, webcam

I'm trying to create a grayscale operation via webcam using OpenCV (cvCapture). Here is the code

```
void h_grayscale( unsigned char* h_in, unsigned char* h_out)
{
for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<width;j++){
       int index = h_in[i*widthStep + j*channels];
       int gray = 0.3*(index)+0.6*(index+1)+0.1*(index+2);
       h_out[i*widthStepOutput+j]=gray;
   }
}

}
```

main code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int c;  
IplImage *image_input; 
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1); 


while(1)
{
    image_input=cvQueryFrame(capture);
    IplImage* image_output = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image_input),IPL_DEPTH_8U,image_input->nChannels);

    unsigned char *h_out = (unsigned char*)image_output->imageData;
    unsigned char *h_in =  (unsigned char*)image_input->imageData;

    width     = image_input->width;
    height    = image_input->height;
    channels  = image_input->nChannels;
    widthStep = image_input->widthStep;
    widthStepOutput = image_input->widthStep;

   h_grayscale ( h_in , h_out ) ;
    //negatif_parallel(h_in, h_out, width, height, widthStep, channels);

    cvShowImage("Original", image_input);
    cvShowImage("CPU", image_output);

    c=cvWaitKey(10);
    if(c == 27)
        break;

   }
return 0;
}
```

but when executed images that appear to be one-third of the overall picture. I do not know which part is wrong.
here the result:
[image: result]

please help mee T_T..thx before :))

Comment: don't use the old c-api, unless you really have to. it's deprecated

Comment: yes you are true.. but its a task from my lecture :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output image is a 3 channel image, thats's why you have only 1/3 of image.

Try to create it with:

```
IplImage* image_output = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image_input),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
```

This code works (try to find the differnces):

```
int height=0;
int width=0;
int channels=0;
int widthStep=0;
int widthStepOutput=0;
void h_grayscale( unsigned char* h_in, unsigned char* h_out);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int c;  
    IplImage *image_input; 
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0); 


    while(1)
    {
        image_input=cvQueryFrame(capture);
        IplImage* image_output = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image_input->width,image_input->height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);

        unsigned char *h_out = (unsigned char*)image_output->imageData;
        unsigned char *h_in =  (unsigned char*)image_input->imageData;

        width     = image_input->width;
        height    = image_input->height;
        channels  = image_input->nChannels;
        widthStep = image_input->widthStep;
        widthStepOutput = image_output->widthStep;

        h_grayscale ( h_in , h_out ) ;
        //negatif_parallel(h_in, h_out, width, height, widthStep, channels);

        cvShowImage("Original", image_input);
        cvShowImage("CPU", image_output);

        c=cvWaitKey(10);
        if(c == 27)
            break;

    }
    return 0;
}

void h_grayscale( unsigned char* h_in, unsigned char* h_out)
{
    for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<width;j++){
            int index = h_in[i*widthStep + j*channels];
            int gray = 0.3*(index)+0.6*(index+1)+0.1*(index+2);
            h_out[i*widthStepOutput+j]=gray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it but still there is an error
"0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0799d000"
in part -->  
          h_out[i*widthStepOutput+j]=gray;

T_T

Comment: oh my god..
 witdhStepOutput its the problem...

thx for ur solution :))